# Search with parameterized in dataset C#?

Tags: dataset

I have the following code used to search the data in the dataset:

```
DataRow[] filteredRows =
                        myDS
                         .Tables["Inventory"]
                         .Select(string.Format("Make LIKE '%{0}%'", keyword));
```

however, if the `keyword` contains data such as `O'Henry` then above command will failed. I can get over this with parameterized with SQLCommand. But I have no idea how to use parameterized with dataset.

Any idea, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `'` with `''`.  (two single-quote characters)